# How to solve a linear stochastic differential equation?

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I don't know how to find a solution of this stochastic differential equation:

$dX_{t}=(1+\delta \mu X_{t})dt+\delta X_{t}dB_{t}$

Where $B_{t}$ is a standard Brownian motion and $\mu$ and $\delta$ are real numbers.

#### Context

I've to demonstrate that  $X_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}\exp{[\delta (B_{t}-\mu t -B_{s}+\mu s)-\frac{1}{2}(t-s)]ds}$

I know   Ito's formula $dY=\dfrac {\partial g}{\partial t} dt + \dfrac {\partial g}{\partial x} dX_t + \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac {\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} dt$ for $Y=g(t,X)$.

Comment: What do you know about stochastic DEs? Do you have any ideas about the answer yourself? It's hard to help if we don't know what you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. First, solve the homogeneous SDE $$dX_t = \delta \mu X_t \, dt + \delta X_t \, dB_t. \tag{1}$$ To this end, apply Itô's formula to $f(x) := \log x$ and $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$.
2. In order to solve the SDE $$dX_t = (1+\delta \mu X_t) \, dt + \delta X_t \, dB_t,$$ we use a variation of constants, i.e. we make the *Ansatz* $$X_t = Z_t X_t^0$$ where $X_t^0$ is a solution of the SDE $(1)$ with initial value $X_0^0=1$. To find the stochastic differential of $(Z_t)_{t \geq 0}$, apply Itô's formula.

**Literature:** The monograph *Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes* by René Schilling & Lothar Partzsch treats (linear) SDEs.

---

**Solution**

1. By Itô's formula, $$\begin{align*} \log X_t-\log X_0 &= \int_0^t \frac{1}{X_s} \, dX_s - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \frac{1}{X_s^2} d\langle X \rangle_s \\ &= \int_0^t \delta \, dB_s + \int_0^t \left(\delta \mu - \frac{1}{2} \delta^2 \right) \, ds \\ &= \delta B_t + \left( \delta \mu - \frac{1}{2} \delta^2 \right) \cdot t. \end{align*}$$ Consequently, $$X_t = X_0 \exp \left( \delta B_t + \left( \delta \mu - \frac{1}{2} \delta^2 \right) t \right).$$
2. Set $Y_t := 1/X_t^0$, i.e. $$Y_t = \exp \left(-\delta B_t - \left( \delta \mu - \frac{1}{2} \delta^2 \right)t \right). \tag{2}$$ Applying Itô's formula yields, $$Y_t - Y_0 =- \delta \int_0^t Y_s \, dB_s + \frac{\delta^2}{2} \int_0^t Y_s \, ds + \left(\frac{\delta^2}{2}-\delta \mu \right) \int_0^t Y_s \, ds,$$ i.e. $$dY_t = -\delta Y_t \, dB_t+(\delta^2- \delta \mu) Y_t \, dt.$$ From $$X_t \cdot Y_t - X_0 = \int_0^t Y_s \, dX_s + \int_0^t X_s \, dY_s + \langle X,Y \rangle_t$$ it follows that $$\begin{align*} Z_t &= X_t Y_t \\ &= X_0+\int_0^t Y_s ((1+\delta \mu X_s) \, ds + \delta X_s) \,dB_s) + \int_0^t X_s \, (-\delta Y_s dB_s + (\delta^2- \delta \mu) Y_s \, ds) \\ &\quad -\delta^2 \int_0^t Y_s X_s \, ds \\ &=X_0+ \int_0^t Y_s \, ds. \end{align*}$$ Note that $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is known explicitly, cf. $(2)$. Consequently, we get $$\begin{align*} X_t &= \frac{Z_t}{Y_t}  \\ &= \exp\left( \delta B_t + \left( \delta \mu- \frac{\delta^2}{2}  \right)t\right) \cdot \left[X_0 + \int_0^t \exp \left(-\delta B_s - \left( \delta \mu - \frac{\delta^2}{2} \right) s \right) \, ds \right]. \end{align*}$$

Comment: So I've 
$X_{t}^{0}=\exp{(\delta \mu t + \delta B_{t})}$

But I don't get how to find $Z_{t}$, I've to demonstrate that

$X_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}\exp{[\delta (B_{t}-\mu t -B_{s}+\mu s)-\frac{1}{2}(t-s)]ds}$

Thank you for your help

Comment: @GiuseppeGuarnuto First, find the stochastic differential of $Y_t := 1/X_t^0$. Then apply Itô's formula to $f(x,y) :=x \cdot y$ and the Itô process $(X_t,Y_t)$.

Comment: ok, I've tried and I found that $dZ_{t}=(Y_{t}+\delta^{2}X_{t}Y_{t}-\frac{1}{2}\delta^{2}Y_{t})dt$ 
so $Z_{t}=(Y_{t}+\delta^{2}X_{t}Y_{t}-\frac{1}{2}\delta^{2}Y_{t})t$ and substituting $Z_{t}$ in $X_{t}=Z_{t}X_{t}^{0}$ I obtain $X_{t}=(t-\frac{1}{2}\delta^{2}t)(1-\delta^{2}t)^{-1}$, so something doesn't work...

Comment: @GiuseppeGuarnuto First of all, your solution $(X_t^0)_{t \geq 0}$ is not correct. You can check that by applying Itô's formula. I have extended my answer, so that you might check your calculations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you're very kind. But your solution is different from the one the I have to demonstrate because there's no $\delta^{2}$, but maybe there's an errore in the problems.

Comment: @GiuseppeGuarnuto Which $\delta^2$ do you mean...? The formula for $(X_t)$ in the 2nd step?

Comment: Yes I mean the last one because I need to demonstrate that Xt=∫exp[δ(Bt−μt−Bs+μs)−1/2(t−s)]ds

Comment: @GiuseppeGuarnuto Checked it with the general solution of a linear SDE (given in the book I mentioned); the solution should be correct.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain me the passage after the equation (2), because I know the It'os formula
 $dY=\dfrac {\partial g}{\partial t} dt + \dfrac {\partial g}{\partial x} dX_t + \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac {\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} dt$
instead you have derivated 2 times with respect to $t$ instead of with respect to $x$.. please can you help me to understand?

Comment: @GiuseppeGuarnuto No, I haven't ... I have 2 times derivated with respect to $x$ and 1 time with respect to $t$. Just write down the derivatives of $g(t,x) := \exp(-a x -bt)$.

Comment: and $dg(t,x)=-bg(t,x)-ag(t,x)+a^{2}g(t,x)$.. so in our case isn't it: $Y_t - Y_0 =- \delta \int_0^t Y_s \, dB_s + \left(\frac{\delta^2}{2}-\delta\mu\right) \int_0^t Y_s \, ds + \delta^{2} \int_0^t Y_s \, ds,$?

Comment: @GiuseppeGuarnuto $\frac{a^2}{2}$ instead of $a^2$ (... the corresponding term is $\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}$.)

Comment: I'm really sorry, it's a my big mistake, thank you so much

Comment: Can I ask you the last question? how is the derivate with respect to $t$ of $\int_{0}^{t}dB_{s}$? and with respect to $x$?

Comment: @GiuseppeGuarnuto What do you mean by that? $B_t = \int_0^t B_s$ is not differentiable with respect to $t$. (...Or $x$ - there is no $x$!)

Comment: but if I have to differentiate $a\left(t-1\right)+bt+\left(1-t\right)\int_{0}^{t}\dfrac{dB_{s}}{1-s}}$ I have to do it...

Comment: Where/Why do you have to do this? I don't see anything of this form in my answer.

Comment: No sorry is another problem, I've just post it in another question